# Not able to do "sudo su - somedir" from a bat file

Tags: sudo, su

I am trying to execute below two commands using a bat file.

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY
plink id@host -pw xxxxxx -m C:\Data\RunCMD.txt
And RunCMD.txt looks like below
ls -lrt
pwd
sudo su - dpa
```

If run the bat file, two commands from RunCMD.txt are working fine but nothing is happening for `sudo su -dpa`. It is getting stuck at this command.

PS- I am able to navigate to dpa user manually. PFB[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "execute below two commands?" Do you mean "execute the command under the first two commands" ie.  the `sudo su` line?  Or do you mean "execute the following two commands"/"execute the two commands below"? (you are actually showing three commands.

Comment: In the second line I am calling a text file which contains 3 commands.Third command in the text file is for sudo. From the image I am trying to show that I am able to  do "sudo su - dpa" but when running it by keeping in text file, it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The prompt in your screenshot shows that you've changed the user from *idXXXXXX* to *dpa*, that's exactly what that command is supposed to do.

Comment: Murphy, from the image I am just trying to show that I am able to do "sudo su - dpa" but same thing while running from the text file it is not working.

Comment: In this case the description of your problem doesn't match the image, which doesn't help us helping you. If you expect useful answers you must provide a succinct example; please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.